# Does Websphere Commerce 7 support JSTL 1.1 XML in widgets?

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl, websphere-8, websphere-commerce

I have made a new blank widget and added it to a page.
All the JSTL tags work normally in its JSP, but trying to do for example

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
<x:set var="test"/>
```

results in an UnresolvableException

```
[19/11/14 17:16:45:617 FET] 0000001f LoggingHelper E /GenericJSPPageError.jsp - $requestScope:EC_device
                             org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.UnresolvableException: $requestScope:EC_device
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil$JstlVariableContext.notNull(XPathUtil.java:377)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil$JstlVariableContext.getVariableValue(XPathUtil.java:322)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil$JstlVariableContext.getVariableOrParam(XPathUtil.java:241)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.fillVarStack(XPathUtil.java:792)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.selectNodes(XPathUtil.java:536)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.SetTag.doStartTag(SetTag.java:69)
...
```

I also have no idea what EC_device is and where it is coming from.
JSTL XML tags are not used anywhere else in the project, so I cannot verify whether they work at all, and hence that is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSTL tags are still valid, it will be an error elsewhere in the code... maybe down to the new directory structure when a widget uses existing resources?